# How to insert the data into two tables?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to insert data into two tables in my database. My script is inserting when all the fields are filled out, but I want to prevent it when I do not provide `img_title`.

post table like this

```
post_id | title 
3         example title
```

images table like this

```
img_id  img_title  post_id
1       nvvm       3
```

when I have not filled the `img_title` it is inserting to images table like this

```
img_id  img_title post_id
1                 3
```

I want to prevent empty field inserting to database

Here is my code

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    include "config.php";

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $img_title = $_POST['img_title'];

    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO post(title,post_id) VALUES (?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $title, $post_id);
    $stmt->execute();

    $post_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);

    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO images(img_title,post_id,img_id) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $img_title, $post_id, $img_id);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo " successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Failed";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use if($img_title !="")

Comment: can you show the result of running `SHOW CREATE TABLE images`?  Ideally you'd have not null constraint - `ALTER TABLE images MODIFY img_title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;`, and then you might need to do `if ($img_title == "") $img_title = null`

Comment: I add after not inserting post table data displays failed message

Comment: The answer below seems to have answered what you asked. What isn't working the way you want it to? Any errors? You checking for them? It's unclear at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try `exit()` to force code execution to terminate when image's title is not set.

```
     <?php
        
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
            include "config.php";
            if(!isset($_POST['img_title'])){
                echo 'test';
                exit();       //You prevented further execution of code if title of image is not set
              }
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $img_title = $_POST['img_title'];
        
            $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO post(title,post_id) VALUES (?,?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $title, $post_id);
            $stmt->execute();
        
            $post_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
        
            $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO images(img_title,post_id,img_id) VALUES (?,?,?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $img_title, $post_id, $img_id);
        
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                echo " successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Failed";
            }
        }
```

Comment: but same results brother it inserting post_id and img_id  without message filed filled

Comment: Are you sure that exit() is being executed? Try echoing something inside the if statement after exit(), and check if it prints something.

Comment: If you checked, tell me. Did the echo statement you inserted below exit() execute?

Comment: I edited. Please tell me whether the word 'test' is printing for you or not.

Comment: I tested but when i insert without message filed it inserting post id and img id to images table i want to prevent it